# prove every language got a language that is harder

Tags: computability, reductions, undecidability

I am prety stuck over here:

> prove or disprove that every $L$ got $L'$ s.t $L'\geq L$ and for every $L''\geq L$
>
> $L''\ngeq L'$
>
> basically it means L' is the hardest...

my intuition tells me that this is correct, but I cant prove why.
I tried to prove using counting but got stuck:

1. we got $\aleph_0$ pairs of functions that we can use in the reduction for both ways
2. we got $\aleph$ languages so there must be a language that got a function to compute the redaction in one way and doesnt got a function for the reduction to the other way

Its feels terribly incorrect any help will be appreciated

EDIT:
I just realized that I didn't write the question correctly please read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The halting problem for a class of machines that can decide $L$ is always harder than $L$. You already know this when $L$ is computable and the proof of the more general result is essentially the same. For every $L$, you need to think of a class of machines that can decide $L$.

Comment: I cant understand, if the language is not in $RE$ than how can I use the halting problem?

Comment: Don't use the halting problem for ordinary Turing machines. You need to think of a class of machines that can decide the langauge you're working with.

Comment: you mean some-thing like $Ld$ ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: all the TM machines that doesn't accept their  encoding